# Android application activity is not changing even after change the code in xml layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

android application activity is not changing even after change the code in xml layout file.i have imported this project in android studio i did all the stuff found on web i.e

1. clean the project
2. build the project
3. applied invalidate caches/Restart
4. synchronize the project

xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#EB5D2F"
>

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

but couldn't solve the problem .please help what can i do.

Comment: activity class or layout are you meaning?

Comment: nothing is reflecting when i am running the app in the emulator . i mean everything remains same

Comment: share your activity & xml file.

Comment: uninstall the app from your emulator and then reinstall it.

Comment: i uninstalled the app every time when running the app in android studio

Comment: @GaganSethi i shared the xml file . and in java code i am just loading the activity

Comment: what do you mean, android application activity is not changing? it above layout xml won't show anything but the color and a toolbar.

Comment: share your activity code